# ModuleNotFoundError trying to use Behave, Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-behave

Rewriting a code from an old little exercise except this time using Behave.
But I can't even start cause I can't make the necessary relative imports.

My directories are:

```
--/Curso_de_Selenium
    --/todo_project
        --/features
            --/steps
                __init__.py
                todo.py
            __init__.py
            environment.py
            todo.feature
        --/page_object
            __init__.py
            page_objects.py
        --/pages
            __init__.py
            elements.py
            pages.py
        __init__.py
        behave.ini
```

All the `__init__` files are only there cause I read somewhere that they are necessary to make python3 interpret the directories as modules. But, so far, they're useless. Could be because they're empty, perhaps.

I've tryed:

```
from Curso_de_Selenium.todo_project.pages.pages import pages
from todo_project.pages.pages import pages
from todo_project.pages import pages
```

But all of them gives me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxxx'`

I also tryed:

```
from C:.Users.lbsme.Desktop.Curso_de_Selenium.todo_project.pages.pages import pages
```

Which gives me a syntax error because of the `:` in `C:`.

I saw a lot of people going through this situation but they were all using pytest so their solutions didn't suit me. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: quick & dirty: `module_name = __import__('path/here')` (*NOTE:* this is not recommended)

Comment: @RocketNikita
Sorry I don't get it...
You mean like
`pages = __import__('C:/Users/lbsme/Desktop/Curso_de_Selenium/todo_project/pages/pages.py')`
?
If that's what you mean, I just tried that and it returned another error:
`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXX
XXXXX escape`.

Comment: This error is from python file that you wanted to import